# Load user file into a PHP template page

Tags: php, html

So I got a little stuck here. As a personal project, I'm trying to make a site a little like Newgorunds.com (in functionality) and I've hit a dead end.

I've decided to have a folder in the root directory for each user uploaded file type, for instance a folder called music. Inside the folder will be all the users names and inside the sub directories will be their uploaded files. I assumed I would need to use scandir to find the files.

My question is, how would I make a list of the the most recent uploads and then, when a user clicks on one of them, how can I get it to open a template page where it loads the file inside a player (for arguments sake, going to use HTML5 player)?

I want something a little like this: http://www.newgrounds.com/audio/browse/sort/date
where it opens up the file (in this case music) in a templated page with the user's name too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a database to store the file data.

Querying it by user or for sorting or just about anything is going to be easier.

For example using your file implementation how would you find all files

- from yesterday
- which are an MP3
- have been uploaded by a user with an unvalidated email address

**The better approach**

When a file is uploaded create a row in a table, that row should contain (at the very least) the file name, the user id for the user that owns the file and the file type.

You can then use this to get a user's files, an example query for getting user 4's mp3 files;

```
SELECT * FROM files WHERE user_id = 4 AND type = 'mp3';
```

You should store the path of the files somewhere else, not in the database. This is because if you ever move the files, e.g to Amazon S3 or to a CDN your database is not broken.

For example;

```
if($file['type'] == "mp3")
    $pathPrefix = "/files/music/";
else if($file['type'] == "document")
    $pathPrefix = "/files/docs/";

$fullPath = $pathPrefix . $file['filename'];

echo "Path is " . $fullPath;
```

If you ever change the destination of the files you can simply change this code, instead of everything in the database.

```
if($file['type'] == "mp3")
    $pathPrefix = "http://s3.amazon.com/abc/music/";
else if($file['type'] == "document")
    $pathPrefix = "http://s3.amazon.com/abc/docs/";
```

Comment: Well, as far as I know, the signup process will create a user subdirectory  in the music folder (and also an SQL entry for their email address and password) and then the upload form will upload the file to the relevant subdirectory since they'll be logged in. I think my main problem here is how do I get a script that loads the file names, prints them as links that then load into a templated page.

Comment: That approach is wrong and unsustainable. I can see the technical issue you have, but this is overshadowed by the flawed approach of storing the files like this with no database implementation. The database can simply store the path of the file. Because if you have a folder with 1,000 folders, each with 100s of files you will soon start to get slow down due to I/O restrictions.

Comment: @Byonex FWIW, I agree with Jake. It makes a lot more sense to use a database to do this.

Comment: I see what you mean. Any suggestions as to how I'd work on creating this approach?

Comment: @Byonex see my edit for an idea

Comment: That's a large help in storing the files, thanks, but how would I go about retrieving a file? By that I mean a list of recent uploads from all users that anyone can see, and the list displays file names and the file names are all linked to a page where that specific song will play.

Comment: The approach is the same you just need to change the query to get all files; `SELECT * FROM files;` You could add a date field to the file data so you can use that in the `WHERE` clause to get recent files. You would then iterate over the results from the database and print out each filename. As for playing the file thats a whole new ball game.